# How to open batch file from IIS hosted website on Intranet

Tags: batch-file, iis, cmd, jar

I have a website with reactJS as frontend and webAPI as backend. I want to open a batch file hosted in webAPI folder which opens cmd, passes some properties to a JAR file in the same folder and runs it.

It works fine in my local dev environment, but when host it on IIS nothing happens. No error in event viewer but but no cmd pops up as well.

I have tried some rights settings in IIS and also on the folder itself based on some answers on stackoverflow as well but, nothing helped. For eg setting defaultAppPool with admin user, connect as admin user, setting admin level privilege's to IIS user itself.

This website will be hosted on the closed Intranet environment,  so there is no issue with security breach.

So is there any other setting available which I can change to open this batch file in this closed secure environment. I don't have issue in moving this JAR folder apart from the website itself to some other folder if required.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming problem.  I think your question would be better served on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) instead.

Comment: Did you add IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool in security of folder and give it the permission of Full control?https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HDiT.png

Comment: @BruceZhang yes I tried that

Comment: @Squashman ok tks :)

Comment: @rscs Is your problem solved?